# Insert Values from one table that is not found in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

I have a table (Table1) in our database that is outdated. The table has columns (ID, Value, ValueDesc,Status). The table we need to update from CorrectTable has columns (Value,narrative,comment,Flag). The value column is distinct and is served as a primary key in both tables.

Here is our issue

1. CorrectTable has about 4000 records that are not found in out Table1
2. Status Column in table one takes a bit datatype (0 or 1) and the corresponding Flag column in CorrectTable has value A or an empty string ( signifying active or not)
3. The Comment column in CorrectTable is not found in our table 1

What we need to do is the following.

1. Somehow insert the records that are in CorrectTable but not in table1 into table 1.
2. Set the status column in table1 as 0, if the flag column is set to empty string.
3. Set the status column in table1 as 1, if the flag column in CorrectTable is A (Active)
4. Populate the comment section from correcttable to the corresponding value column in table1 (we are going to be creating that column in table1). This needs to happen for all the values, not just the ones that don't exist in table1.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following query for this. I really hope that will help you

```
Merge TargetTableName USING SourceTableName
ON Merging_Condition
WHEN MATCHED
THEN Update_Query
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN Insert_Query
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN DELETE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the merge statement when not matched by target clause is where you execute steps 1-4.

```
merge into table1 
using correcttable
when not matched by target
begin
   insert....
   update....
end
```